# p:fileUpload doesn't work inside p:dialog

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, dialog

I'm trying to upload a file using PrimeFaces p:fileUpload inside p:dialog but it doesn't work

```
<h:form id="form3"> 
       <p:commandLink value="upload" oncomplete="PF('Dialog').show()" />            
       <p:dialog  widgetVar="submitDialog" modal="true"  >
              <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
                     <h:panelGrid id="submitPanelGrid" columns="2"  >
                         <p:fileUpload  id="upload" value="#{bean.file}"  mode="simple" sizeLimit="100000"  />
                         <p:commandButton id="btn3" action="#{bean.submit()}"  icon="ui-icon-circle-check" ajax="false"  /> 
                     </h:panelGrid>
                 </p:panel>
              </h:form>
       </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

I'm getting this exception just after I click on the link:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream,
>   content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;

But outside `<p:dialog>`, it works just fine.

Comment: Did you try specify the multipart in the form? ex: <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: yes i've tried and it didn't work

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed in html (and jsf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a form inside of another is not allowed in html, you have to separate the dialog from the main form, and for the exception you are getting you have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your dialog form :

```
   <h:form id="form3"> 
         <p:commandLink value="upload" oncomplete="PF('Dialog').show()" />      
   </h:form>      

   <p:dialog  widgetVar="submitDialog" modal="true"  >
          <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
                 <h:panelGrid id="submitPanelGrid" columns="2"  >
                     <p:fileUpload  id="upload" value="#{bean.file}"  mode="simple" sizeLimit="100000"  />
                     <p:commandButton id="btn3" action="#{bean.submit()}"  icon="ui-icon-circle-check" ajax="false"  /> 
                 </h:panelGrid>
             </p:panel>
          </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Change 'Dialog' to 'submitDialog', as PF must reference the widgetVar.